# Why is there current through this MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, simulation, multisim

This is an N-type enhancement MOSFET, and from what I understand, there should be no source - drain current flowing when there is no voltage applied to the gate.

Why is there current flowing in this circuit? Is there a problem with the simulator? I have not touched any MOSFET's default parameters.

The software is Multisim

[image]

Comment: Because you have connected the MOSFET backward and now the MOSFET body diode is conducting current.

Comment: After flipping both vertically and horizontally, everything is as it should. Thank you.

Comment: Every MOSFET has a built-in body diode between the drain and the source.
In your case, the anode of a body diode is connected to the source terminal and the cathode to the drain terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the note I attached to your circuit image: -

[image]

So, no matter what the MOSFET does or how it appears to be deactivated, current will flow through the body diode.

Comment: Is it conventional for schematic symbols to show the body diode? The symbol at the start of the [ONSEMI 2N7000 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nds7002a-d.pdf) shows the body diode, but the symbol is the Multisim simulation circuit doesn't.

Comment: @ChesterGillon what is your point?

Comment: I suspect that Chester's point is that they don't know whether or not it's conventional for schematic symbols to show the body diode, and they would like to find out. For what it's worth, my experience is that sometimes the body diode is shown and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: @ChesterGillon The triangle inside the symbol indicates the substrate-channel diode.